# What Python based Dashboard options exist?

Tags: python, ruby, monitoring, dashboard, health-monitoring

I want to create a Dashboard on each server to show it's health and the results of some daily processing. I plan to hook up shell scripts and Python programs to collect the data.

Instead of writing a web-based interface, I thought it would be good to use a python based web dashboard that could render the results in various business user and manager friendly formats.

What are my options to do this? I am primarily interested in Python RedHat Linux, but other platforms are interesting too.

I'm also open to Perl and Ruby based solutions especially if the plugins can be language neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ZenOSS](http://www.zenoss.com/) , it is written in python and you can extend it using python.